# Unable to login to ubuntu 18.04 (only via wayland)

Tags: 18.04, xorg, login-screen, xserver

I have a `DELL inspiron 15-5567` and my graphics card is `AMD radeon R7 M445` running Ubuntu 18;04.3. Suddenly after going to an `apt-get upgrade` my desktop is not logging the user account into xorg session anymore.
The solutions related to `nvidia` or `amd-gpu` proprietory graphics card doesnt work cause i don't have any of these installed.
Here is the output of `cat ~\.Xauthority`

> no such user or named directory: .Xauthority

output of `cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log`

> no such file or directory: /var/log/Xorg.0.log

output of `cat ~\.xsession-errors`

> openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
>   cannot connect to brltty at :0
>   upstart: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_usr_bin_uget-integrator.1000.crash) main process (2244) terminated with status 127
>   upstart: unity-gtk-module main process (2193) terminated with status 71
>   upstart: bamfdaemon main process (2352) terminated with status 1
>   upstart: hud main process (2474) terminated with status 1
>   upstart: unity-settings-daemon main process (2476) terminated with status 1
>   upstart: gnome-session (Unity) main process (2484) terminated with status 1
>   upstart: Iris main process (2494) killed by ABRT signal
>   upstart: unity-panel-service main process (2498) terminated with status 1
>   upstart: indicator-bluetooth main process (2520) killed by TERM signal
>   upstart: indicator-power main process (2521) killed by TERM signal
>   upstart: indicator-datetime main process (2527) killed by TERM signal
>   upstart: indicator-keyboard main process (2528) terminated with status 1
>   upstart: indicator-printers main process (2534) terminated with status 1
>   upstart: indicator-session main process (2539) killed by TERM signal
>   upstart: indicator-application main process (2548) killed by TERM signal
>   upstart: unity7 main process (2708) terminated with status 1
>   upstart: indicator-application pre-stop process (2781) terminated with status 255
>   upstart: gnome-session (Unity) pre-stop process (2782) terminated with status 127
>   upstart: Disconnected from notified D-Bus bus
>   upstart: gpg-agent post-stop process (2784) terminated with status 127

also i tried reinstalling `xorg`, `update-notifier` & `ubuntu-desktop` from wayland, reconfigured gdm3 via `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3`.
and tried command `sudo chown ishan:ishan /home/ishan`.
None of these did work for me.
Any Suggestions?

**EDIT:**
Output to `sudo startx` is

> X.Org X Server 1.19.6
>   Release Date: 2017-12-20
>   X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
>   Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-148-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
>   Current Operating System: Linux ishan-Inspiron-5567 4.15.0-64-generic #73-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 12 13:16:13 UTC 2019 x86_64
>   Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-64-generic   root=UUID=4a787948-8e50-4f9f-8a86-11eda8327781 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=1
>   Build Date: 03 June 2019  08:10:35AM
>   xorg-server 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.3 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support)
>   Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
>       Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
>       to make sure that you have the latest version.
>   Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
>       (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
>       (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
>   (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.1.log", Time: Mon Sep 30 21:21:54 2019
>   (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
>   xf86: found device 1
>   xinit: connection to X server lost
>   waiting for X server to shut down ..(II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.

And output of `cat /var/log/Xorg.1.log` is [here](https://pastebin.com/C8iPr97a)

Comment: I see a mix of gnome and unity.  `cat /var/log/installer/lsb-release` please edit your question for output.

Comment: It was a fresh install of ubuntu  18.04.1 actually. here is the output:
`cat: /var/log/installer/lsb-release: No such file or directory`

Comment: also the output of `cat /var/log/installer/media-info` is  >`Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS "Bionic Beaver" - Release amd64 (20180725)%`

Comment: why upstart? You have unity and gnome3?  `readlink -f /sbin/init` please.

Comment: I recently installed GPGV2 before the login loop but dont think it is somewhat related to this. Anyways the output of `readlink -f /sbin/init` is `/lib/systemd/systemd`

Comment: I don't have upstart installed either.